# eclipse plugin, run some method after running the program

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am writing an eclipse plugin , and I want to show a message after the user has successfully run the code that he has written in the active editor page. how should I know when the user runs his code?

Comment: Please post code of the "program"

Comment: sorry , the question was phrased badly ... I edited it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add an `IDebugEventSetListener` listener for debug events that will be notified about programs being run / debugged.

```
DebugPlugin.getDefault().addDebugEventListener(listener);
```